# combining "though" and "but"

Tags: conjunctions, negation, run-on-sentences

Is it okay to use "though" and "but" in a sentence like this:

> If you were wondering why I have two accounts it is because the other one is too public **though** I'm still using it **but** I'm no longer posting or updating my status and whatsoever effin stuffs.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

Basically its OK, but such a long sentence can be difficult to follow and understand. So rather than use so many conjuctions you could break it up into two sentences where the topics are not the same. For example:

> If you were wondering why *I* have two accounts, it is because the other one is too public.
>   I'm still using it but (I'm) no longer posting or updating my status and whatsoever effin stuffs.

The first sentence should have a comma to indicate a natural pause between the query and response.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatically, "though" is used whenever the speaker has a "second thought" (remembers or suddenly realizes a reason or evidence to support the opposing position). It's also a short version of -- and less formal than -- "although." You seem to be using it as one would say "even though" in this context:

> "If you were wondering why i have two accounts it is because the other
>   one is too public, **even though** I'm still using it, but I'm no
>   longer posting or updating my status and whatsoever effin stuffs."

"Even though" is used in the same context as "in spite of the fact that.." or "despite the fact that..."
I'm not completely sure on this, though. Your sentence is a little difficult to understand.

It's also crucial that you place commas before conjunctions that join two or more sentences together, otherwise your sentences become a mess to read.